# jquery mobile collapsible listview doesnt work with li tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I tried collapsible listview but does not work why?
*such as:*

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c">
   <h3>LIST</h3>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

if click the header,should be open the other 'li' tags.how can i do that?
[image]

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/263/

Comment: not exactly what i want.Could you give an example of a comprehensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a [collapsibleset](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/collapsibleset/):

```
<div data-role="collapsibleset">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h2>List</h2>   
        <ul data-role="listview">
          <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uG6Cg/)**